# Finding n matching files by sub-path recursively inside a directory

Tags: powershell

I have a file structure like:

1. RootDir\

   - ADir
   - - 1.xml
   - - 2.xml
   - BDir
   - - 1.xml
   - - 2.xml
   - - 3.xml
   - CDir
   - - 2.xml
   - - 3.xml

I need to write script to recursively check if a file exists in more than one directory under RootDir, where the file path is identical from one level below RootDir.

For example **RootDir\ADir\1.xml** also exists in location **RootDir\BDir\1.xml**

The code below returns the path of matching entries, however it also continues to match with iteself, despite the -exclude switch

```
$rootCompare = "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Compare\RootDir"
$rootItems = get-childitem -Path C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Compare\RootDir -Recurse
foreach ($i in $rootItems){
$dirItems = get-childitem $i -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
   $fullName = $_.fullName
   $baseName = $_.baseName
   $baseExt = $_.Extension
   Write-Host "fullname="$fullName
   if (Test-Path $rootCompare\*\$baseName$baseExt -Exclude $fullName) {
       $fileSearch = get-ChildItem -Path $rootCompare\*\$baseName$baseExt -Exclude "*$fullName*"
       Write-Host "searching for file: "$fullName
       Write-Host "file exists in another location: "$fileSearch
       }
   }
}
```

Example return:

```
fullname= C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Compare\RootDir\CDir\3.xml
searching for file:  C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Compare\RootDir\CDir\3.xml
file exists in another location:  C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Compare\RootDir\ADir\3.xml 
C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Compare\RootDir\CDir\3.xml
```

1) How can I adapt the exclude condition to prevent it from matching with itself?

2) This version only works at 1 level below RootDir. How should it be adapted to work n levels below RootDir?

For example **RootDir\ADir\DDir\1.xml** should also match **RootDir\BDir\DDir\1.xml** but not **RootDir\ADir\1.xml**

Important point:

- The number, name and paths the of directories are dynamic and cannot be hard-coded

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way of how I would do it is to do a single `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` into a variable. Then I could iterate through that variable twice. Once to get the first list of objects, and a second to compare to the first. Then in the comparison we want to match where the Name is the same, *and* the FullName doesn't match.

```
$rootCompare = "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Compare\RootDir"
$rootItems = get-childitem -Path $rootCompare -Recurse

foreach ($i in $rootItems){
    foreach ($j in $rootItems){
        if($i.Name -eq $j.Name -and $i.fullName -ne $j.fullName)
        {
            Write-Host "file" $i.fullName
            Write-Host "also exists in another location: "$j.fullName
        }
     }
}
```